# Is this die from an RPG?

Tags: dice, product-identification

The following die is light black plastic, with gold paint on the carved side icons, and is 0.5 inches in length, width, and height.

Is this die from an RPG? If so, which RPG? 
Does the die have a name? 
 
Do the symbols have names and or meanings? If so, can you describe them? 
[image: 3 sides of die]
[image: Other 3 sides of die]

Comment: Would it be possible to provide sharper images? It's hard to see some of these symbols.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These aren't from an RPG, they are from the [Star Wars Galactic Battle Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/75702/star-wars-galactic-battle-game) by Hasbro. Clearer image:

[image]

The symbols on the dice correspond to skills. Rolling the die grants a bonus to the corresponding attribute. Each card has its own list of bonuses, but lists all the attributes and their corresponding symbols:

[image]

Comment: Who's this Han Solotm guy? Is he an Expanded Universe character or something? `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Han Solo (Tauntaun Mounted)?

Comment: Thanks.  This die was in my desk when I started work at a new company 18 months ago.  It sits on top of the desk and every couple of months I go online and tried to search for the source.  The answer is even better than I could have hoped. I'm old enough to have seen all the Star Wars films as  first runs, in the theatre.

Comment: @FrankLaPlante I used Kevin Cook's http://www.dicecollector.com/ - the website for largest dice collection in the world, with a very 1990s design sentiment but a pretty comprehensive filtering tool for managing the thousands of dice inside.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic but this is truly hypnotizing http://www.dicecollector.com/DICEINFO_ANIMATIONS_MINE.html

Comment: Oh my god... Han Solo has a Force ability. And it's as good as his Battle skills and Luck. Hasbro, why are you doing this to us...